# Bringing UIViews to front on tap

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

https://github.com/raylu135/Views-
I'm working on this project, I'd like to add a function that allows me to bring the tapped view to the front.
After some researches, I tried to add an `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `view.bringSubviewToFront` but it didn't work... maybe I'm not doing it the right way, how can I do?

Comment: I posted my GitHub link, i deleted the other part because it didn't work, what do you need to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work like in the link.

1, You need to setup the tap gesture recogniser

2, You need to create an @objc function and call this on action.

```
//paste it into viewDidLoad. 
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
//Uncomment next line, if you want more than one tap to activate gesture.
//tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 5
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

// Create a function
@objc func tapped(){
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(UIViewWhatYouWantToBringToFront)
}
```

Comment: Dris is right. You are calling `#selector(UIView.endEditing(_:))` and you should replace it with your own method. You *have* to mark it as @objc or @IBAction in order for it to work.

Comment: Perfect, I added multiple gesture recognisers in order to be able to bring each view to the front and now it works fine, thanks!